# Azure DevOps S3 React/MERN stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azure-devops, devops

Does anyone have any experience of using Azure DevOps to deploy React build package to AWS using their extension?

I'm stuck on uploading only the build package of npm build.

Here is my scripts so far:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm test
    npm run build
    - task: S3Upload@1
      inputs:
        awsCredentials: 'AWS Deploy User'
        regionName: 'us-east-1'
        bucketName: 'test'
        globExpressions: '**'
        createBucket: true
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

The only options on the task for S3Upload that stands out is sourceFolder. They use something like `"$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"` but since I've never used that before that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Would it just be as simple as like `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build`

[image]

Comment: With these current settings I get:
No files found in "../../work/1/a" that match pattern "**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` is mapped to `c:\agent_work\1\a`, which is the local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination.

In your yaml pipeline, your source code is downloaded in folder `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`(ie. `c:\agent_work\1\s`). And the npm commands in the script task all runs in this folder. So the npm build result is this folder `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\build` (ie.c:\agent_work\1\s\build).

S3Upload task will upload file from $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) by default. You can specifically point the `sourceFolder` attribute  (default is `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`) of S3Upload task to folder `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\build`. See below:

```
- task: S3Upload@1
      inputs:
        awsCredentials: 'AWS Deploy User'
        regionName: 'us-east-1'
        bucketName: 'test'
        globExpressions: '**'
        createBucket: true
        sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build'
```

Another workaround is to use copy file task to copy the build results from `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\build` to folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. See example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code#react-and-vue).

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: 'build/**' # Pull the build directory (React)
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: I did that and got the following error:
##[error]Error: Not found sourceFolder: /home/vsts/work/1/s\buil

Comment: It seems backward slash '\' isnot recognized in linux. Try changing to `sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build` with forward slash '/'

Comment: I actually just barely caught that as you said that!

Comment: Since you are probably more familiar with the pipelines. Is there a way to verison a build package and put it in the artificats from the pipeline? Cause I'm using S3 to host the UI so I'm hoping this will just over ride the files. But when I override the files I lose that verison.

Comment: You mean versioning your build package like this `buildpackage.1.0.0.zip`?

Comment: Yeah I guess, kind of new to this whole concept but want to explore it more. So Say this build goes through even tho all the test pass and stuff we found a bug, and we want to revert back to a previous version. Instead of updating master shouldn't we store these packages somewhere? Not sure what is best practice here but know something long those lines should be practice.

Comment: In addition I see there is the release pipeline but how do we know to add version the release? Looking at the "release" option doesn't look like it supports an S3 upload

Comment: You can use release pipeline to do this. First you need to use publish build artifact to publish the build package to azure devops server. Then create a release pipeline, add a stage, You can add S3 upload task in the stages. See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops) to create release pipeline. You can go to the azure devops project settings-->pipeline-->settings/release retention to set how long the release should be retained, so that you can revert back later

Comment: But the "Release pipeline" does not appear to have anything like upload to S3 or Amazon or anything correct if I'm looking at it correctly? Seems everything is Azure App Service.

Comment: If you installed `AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps` extension in your azure organization. You should be able to find S3 upload task when you are trying to add a task in the stage jobs. I can see this task in my release stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217498/discussion-between-setupg-and-levi-lu-msft).